# How to do serialization in Miracl library?

Tags: c++, encryption

Is there a way to do serialization in C++ Miracl library ?

Typically, in Crypto world we would do encryption routine and decryption(like AES,RSA) routine in two differenti program, I want the same structure in these pairing based Encryption like the Attributed-based Encryption and Broadcast Encryption , i.e implement Encryption function in one program and Decryption in another program. There are some example programs in Miracl repo [this](https://github.com/miracl/MIRACL/blob/master/source/curve/pairing/bgw.cpp) and [this](https://github.com/miracl/MIRACL/blob/master/source/curve/pairing/cpabe.cpp).  But they do encryption , keygen and decryption in one program.

So I need dump the ciphers produced in Encryption (Mostly ,they are elements in G1 and GT , sometime Big objects) into files, and reload it in Decryption program , is there a way to do this kind of work?  Functions in Miracl or from other libs?

More specifically, Can I just save the element in G1 to bytes . By call

```
G1 a;
std::cout << sizeof(a) << std::endl;
```

It outpus 40. Can I just save the 40 bytes and reload it again? Is it possible?

Comment: `#include <type_traits>  int main() { std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable<G1>(); }` -- Inspect the output value.  If it is 0, then the answer to your question is *no, you cannot simply dump out the bytes of that class to a file*.  Also, are you aware that `sizeof` is a compile-time value?  It is not clear what your intentions are with that line of code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well, that line of code is just want to mention the size of the object, and I want to save the bytes as less as possible.  In this situation , if the size of G1 are 40 bytes, can I just save 40 bytes in file?

Comment: *if the size of G1 are 40 bytes, can I just save 40 bytes in file?* -- I guess you didn't understand the first part of my comment.  If the object is not trivially copyable, or if it contains pointers, the answer is "no".  You have to serialize the object properly.

Comment: Except for the Mircal library, are there any other libraries for the bilinear map?

Comment: @Land According to my knowledge, [pbc](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/manual.html)  is another choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a build functions spill and restore inside G1, G2 and GT classes. you can use them to spill G1 into a char* and restore G1 back using char*.

```
For example:-

pfc.precomp_for_mult(Q);  // precomputation based on fixed point Q
char *bytes;             
int len=Q.spill(bytes);   // allocates byte array of length len
..                        // ..and spills precomputation into it  
Q.restore(bytes);         // restores Q from byte array (and deletes array)
```